# Programa que faz a soma/multiplicação de 2 números e o que há entre eles e imprime

Tags: c, algoritmo, operadores

Creio que a lógica deste programa está certa, mas o resultado está vindo errado.

Faça um programa que receba dois números X e Y, sendo X < Y. Calcule e mostre:

- a soma dos números pares desse intervalo de números, incluindo os números digitados;
- a multiplicação dos números ímpares desse intervalo, incluindo os digitados

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0, somaPares = 0, multiImpares = 0;

    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);

    somaPares = (x+y);
    multiImpares = (x*y);
    printf("%d\n", somaPares);
    printf("%d\n", multiImpares);

    while (x<y)
    {
        x++;
        if(x%2==0){
            somaPares = somaPares + x;
        }
        else {
            multiImpares = multiImpares*x;
        }
    }

    printf("A soma de X e Y mais os números pares entre eles é: %d\n", &somaPares);
    printf("A multiplicação de X e Y mais os números ímpares entre eles é: %d", &multiImpares);
}
```

A entrada que estou colocando é: 5 e 3, sendo 8 a soma e 15 o resultado, nos dois primeiros `printfs` está vindo correto, agora nos dois últimos `printfs` está me retornando respectivamente, 2752260 e 2752256.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só retirar o operador `&` nos `printf()` finais. Eles estão mandando imprimir o endereço das variáveis e não seu conteúdo. Se quer o conteúdo, use o nome da variável simples. Talvez tenha se confundido com o `scanf()` que exige o operador para passar por referência e a variável receber o novo valor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    int somaPares = x + y;
    int multiImpares = x * y;
    printf("%d\n", somaPares);
    printf("%d\n", multiImpares);
    while (x < y) {
        x++;
        if (x % 2 == 0) somaPares += x;
        else multiImpares *= x;
    }
    printf("A soma de X e Y mais os números pares entre eles é: %d\n", somaPares);
    printf("A multiplicação de X e Y mais os números ímpares entre eles é: %d", multiImpares);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/BA8Bi4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jhcewluj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SumProduct.c).

Talvez o algoritmo também esteja errado mas aí eu não posso ter certeza. Respondi o que foi perguntado e o que está claro na pergunta.

Comment: Há um problema aí, no enunciado diz, que x seja menor que y

Comment: Não entendi. Você está vendo algum problema? Qual seria?

Comment: Na questão diz "sendo X < Y", então o código não poderia permitir um X maior que um Y, o Alexandre também estava equivocado ao testar com 5 e 3.. Mas isso é questão de detalhe e organização rsrs

Comment: É, eu vi que tem algumas coisas esquisitas no código mas a dúvida dele era sobre a impressão errada do valor. Alguém pode ter entendido que o meu tem algo errado porque recebi um negativo que não sei porque.

Comment: Entendo, comigo aconteceu o mesmo talvez só porque troquei o `while` por for, para ter um código mais enxuto.. O erro dele era o mesmo que o meu ontem rsrs

Answer (score 0):

O `while` pode errado..E o `&` nos `printf`
Com `for` :

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(void)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0, cont, pares = 0, impares = 1;
    while(x >= y)
    { // trate x como menor que y, como o pedido
        scanf("%d", &x);
            scanf("%d", &y);
    }

    printf("Soma = %i\n", (x + y));
    printf("Produto = %i\n", (x * y));

    for(cont = x; cont <= y; cont ++)
    {
        if(cont % 2 == 0)
            pares += cont;
        else
            impares *= cont;
    }
    printf("Resultado:\n");
    printf("Pares = %i\n", pares);
    printf("Impares = %i\n", impares);
}
```

Veja [ele rodando](http://ideone.com/BLQCYH) com valores 3 para x e 9 para y pois x tem de ser menor que y.

Comment: O `while` o que?

Comment: Eu não analisei o código dele, pois prefiro o `for` nesses casos, olhei agora, o `while` está correto..